# FileExists returns true but file doesn't exist

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I write my program in Delphi 7. I only need it to work on non-Unicode filenames. If it finds a Unicode filename it should just ignore it.

My code looks like this:

```
var Filename: String;

if not FileExists(Filename) then Exit;

F := TFileStream(Filename, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
```

However in case of some Unicode filenames the FileExists() returns true but then TFileStream raises an exception because the path is invalid.

For example:
A file named: "loop 輪紋.jpg" is read into Filename as "loop ??.jpg". This is expected behavior. TFileStream cannot read such file (because there is no "loop ??.jpg" in the directory) and raises an exception. But FileExists() should catch that this file doesn't exist. Why it doesn't work? Because it is defined as:

```
function FileExists(const FileName: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := FileAge(FileName) <> -1;
end;
```

and FileAge() is defined as:

```
function FileAge(const FileName: string): Integer;
var
  Handle: THandle;
  FindData: TWin32FindData;
  LocalFileTime: TFileTime;
begin
  Handle := FindFirstFile(PChar(FileName), FindData);
...
```

FindFirstFile uses "loop ??.jpg" as a mask and then finds "loop 輪紋.jpg".

**So the question is eiter:**

1) Can I in Delphi 7 somehow easily use Unicode filenames in TFileStream?

or

2) What function should I use instead of FileExists to get correct results?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Not with `TFileStream` itself, no. But you can instead use the Win32 [`CreateFileW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) to open the Unicode filename, and then assign the returned `HANDLE` to a [`THandleStream`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.THandleStream).  That is essentially what `TFileStream` does internally (using `CreateFileA()` instead in Delphi 7).
2. Later versions of Delphi use the Win32 [`GetFileAttributes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesa) <sup>1</sup> instead of the RTL's `FileAge()` in their implementation of `FileExists()`.  `GetFileAttributes()` does not support wildcards, like `FindFirstFile()` does.

   <sup>1.</sup> See [Why is GetFileAttributes the way old-timers test file existence?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071023-00/?p=24713)

Or, you could simply not check for file existence at all before opening the file, just open it unconditionally and catch the resulting error. The OS will tell you whether the failure is due to the file not being found vs some other error.

Comment: Thank you, Remy, this is a very detailed answer!

Comment: Great answer as always, but I would put even more emphasis on the last part. Opening a file can go wrong for many reasons, just just trying to open it is better than to check for each of them before.

Comment: @GolezTrol I don't just check if file exists. If file doesn't exist I look for another file. Handling exceptions when reading a file is a must but using exceptions to just check if file exists is not elegant.

Comment: If you only want to know if it exists, yes. But you wanted to open it, right? In that case, just try to open it. Of course it depends on the flow that you want. If you _don't_ want to  open the other file if file one is broken, read-only, protected, or on a damaged disk, then it makes sense to check if the file exists. If you just want to open A or B, I'd just try to open A, and on failure try to open B.

Comment: @Tom "*If file doesn't exist I look for another file ... using exceptions to just check if file exists is not elegant*" - you can use #1 in my answer to address that. Open a file with `CreateFileW()`. If it fails, check `GetLastError()`. If that returns `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` or `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, try the next file. If any other error occurs, or you exhaust the files you want to try, raise an exception and quit. If any file opens, create a `THandleStream` for it and move on. This avoids the use of exceptions for checking existence, and lets the OS check the existence for you.